# Gulp how to save output to file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using `gulp` and `gulp-shell`. How do I save output to a file (created by `gulp`) ?

```
return gulp.src('.')
    .pipe(shell([
        'composer install --prefer-source'
    ]));
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this I use `gulp-exec`.

```
gulp.task("git_log", [], function(){
    var options = {
        continueOnError: false, // default = false, true means don't emit error event
        pipeStdout: true, // default = false, true means stdout is written to file.contents
        customTemplatingThing: "test" // content passed to gutil.template()
    };
    var reportOptions = {
        err: false, // default = true, false means don't write err
        stderr: true, // default = true, false means don't write stderr
        stdout: false // default = true, false means don't write stdout
    };
    return gulp.src("somefile.txt")
        .pipe(exec("pwd", options))
        .pipe(exec.reporter(reportOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp Shell passes files not the output of the commands it runs.

A quick and dirty solution — that is *not* windows friendly nor gulp based — would be to simply pass the output of the shell command to a file within the command itself:

```
return gulp.src('.')
  .pipe(shell([
    'composer install --prefer-source > composer-log.txt'
  ]));
```

This is obviously only suitable for *nix environments, and doesn't scale well for capturing the output of multiple commands (although you could just append the output from all those commands to the same file).

Answer (score -1):

continue with `.pipe(gulp.dest('output.file'))`.

Comment: It just create directory output.file/project-directory/ which is empty

Comment: @Thomas gulp-shell just passes through the source files, not the output of the commands it runs on them, so you are essentially piping the current directory into the current directory.

Answer (score -1):

You could better use run to do this.

```
gulp.task 'run',->
run ("echo Hello!")
.exec()
.pipe (gulp.dest "G:\\new.txt")
```

Install needed plugins for this like gulp-run and gulp-exec.